# Add Mac Excel Shortcuts when command is in the ribbon but not the menu bar

Tags: excel, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, pivot-table, ribbon

I'd like to add keyboard shortcuts for Mac Excel commands that are normally accessed by clicking an icon in the ribbon.

For example, I'd like a keyboard shortcut that opens the PivotTable Builder, which is used to modify an existing PivotTable.

However, as far as I can tell, in Mac Excel 2011 the PivotTable Builder can only be accessed through the Ribbon, and the keyboard shortcut maker only lists commands that are stored in the Menu Bar.

How can I add keyboard shortcuts to access commands that are not listed in the Menu Bar, but are accessed by clicking icons in the Ribbon?

In addition, is there a way to create keyboard shortcuts for commands that are only accessed by first right-clicking?